# Nib file designing in Xcode 9 using IB

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xcode9.2

I am making ios app, and I am beginer in iOS. I am making an app and in this I am trying to make the custom tableview cell.

For this I Have added a cocoa touch class and also check to create its nib file.

Now in IB I am putting views like UiLabel,Buttons etc int it , making its height bigger in IB. But this is not updating the View. I can not see any thing inside the View.

> I want to see it visually so that I can set autolayout constraints
>   through IB. Did any one notice this thing? Why the view of IB is not
>   updating? I have started my mac. but it did not help. Any suggestion
>   please?
>
> **Note:** I am using Xcode 9.2

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered your nib file as UITableViewCell? First you need to register your nib file in viewDidLoad of your class where you have dropped the outlet of your tableView.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CustomOneCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCellOne")
    }
```

After this, go to your tableView delegates,

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCellOne", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomOneCell
        return cell
    }
```

Make sure to assign the tableview delegate and datasource.